# javascript: check if PageRequestManager pageLoad already fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Let's say there is a function that registers event handler for page load:

```
function onLoad(pageLoadedHandler) {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler)
}
```

As it turned out, if page is already loaded **pageLoadedHandler** will not be called. I want **onLoad** function to call passed event handler if page is already loaded, so how can we check this?

We can go with some ugly way like this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded( function () {
    window.pageIsAlreadyLoaded = true;
} );

function onLoad(pageLoadedHandler) {
    if(window.pageIsAlreadyLoaded){
        pageLoadedHandler();
    } else {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);
    }
}
```

It will only require putting this code to the early loaded JS file. But there should be a nice way to do this checking.